# Comparing timestamps in dataframe columns with pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, compare

Lets say I have a dataframe like this

df1:

```
         datetime1                datetime2             
0   2021-05-09 19:52:14      2021-05-09 20:52:14  
1   2021-05-09 19:52:14      2021-05-09 21:52:14 
2           NaN                      NaN
3  2021-05-09 16:30:14               NaN
4           NaN                      NaN
5  2021-05-09 12:30:14        2021-05-09 14:30:14
```

I want to compare the timestamps in datetime1 and datetime2 and create a new column with the difference between them.

In some scenarios I have a cases that I don't have values in datetime1 and datetime2, or I have values in datatime1 but I don't in datatime2, so is there is a possible way to get NaN in "difference" column if there is no timestamp in datetime1 and 2, and if there is a timestamp only in datetime1, get the difference compared to datetime.now() and put that in another column.

Desirable df output:

```
         datetime1             datetime2          Difference in H:m:s    Compared with datetime.now()
0   2021-05-09 19:52:14     2021-05-09 20:52:14       01:00:00                 NaN
1   2021-05-09 19:52:14     2021-05-09 21:52:14       02:00:00                 NaN
2           NaN                    NaN                  NaN                    NaN
3   2021-05-09 16:30:14            NaN                  NaN                e.g(04:00:00)
4           NaN                    NaN                  NaN                    NaN
5  2021-05-09 12:30:14    2021-05-09 14:30:14         02:00:00                 NaN
```

I tried a solution from  @AndrejKesely, but it is failing if there is no timestamp in datetime1 and datetime2:

```
def strfdelta(tdelta, fmt):
    d = {"days": tdelta.days}
    d["hours"], rem = divmod(tdelta.seconds, 3600)
    d["minutes"], d["seconds"] = divmod(rem, 60)
    return fmt.format(**d)


# if datetime1/datetime2 aren't already datetime, apply `.to_datetime()`:
df["datetime1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime1"])
df["datetime2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime2"])

df["Difference in H:m:s"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: strfdelta(
        x["datetime2"] - x["datetime1"],
        "{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}",
    ),
    axis=1,
)
print(df)
```

Comment: Could you just do ```df.dropna(inplace=True)``` to get rid of NaN values and then do the method?

Comment: It is removing me the rows with NaN values and I don't want to remove them. I want them there like in the desirable dataframe output that I mention in my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select only rows match conditions by using boolean indexing (mask) to do what you need and let Pandas fill missing values with NaN:

```py
def strfdelta(td: pd.Timestamp):
    seconds = td.total_seconds()
    hours = int(seconds // 3600)
    minutes = int((seconds % 3600) // 60)
    seconds = int(seconds % 60)
    return f"{hours:02}:{minutes:02}:{seconds:02}"

bm1 = df["datetime1"].notna() & df["datetime2"].notna()
bm2 = df["datetime1"].notna() & df["datetime2"].isna()

df["Difference in H:m:s"] = (df.loc[bm1, "datetime2"] - df.loc[bm1, "datetime1"]).apply(strfdelta)

df["Compared with datetime.now()"] = (datetime.now() - df.loc[bm2, "datetime1"]).apply(strfdelta)
```

```py
>>> df

            datetime1           datetime2   Diff...    Comp...
0 2021-05-09 19:52:14 2021-05-09 20:52:14  01:00:00        NaN
1 2021-05-09 19:52:14 2021-05-09 21:52:14  02:00:00        NaN
2                 NaT                 NaT       NaN        NaN
3 2021-05-09 16:30:14                 NaT       NaN  103:09:19
4                 NaT                 NaT       NaN        NaN
5 2021-05-09 12:30:14 2021-05-09 14:30:14  02:00:00        NaN
```

Comment: Thanks @Corralien

Comment: Is there I way I can print the difference only in hours and not in days? for example if the difference is 30:00:00 to be printed like 30:00:00 and not 1 day 06:00:00?

Comment: Do what you want with your `strfdelta` function. If you prefer only the fixed format H: m: s, your function can be simpler.

Comment: how can i change the strfdelta function to print "difference" column only in hours not in days?

Comment: @user14073111, I updated the `strfdelta` function.

Comment: Thanks a lot @corralien, it is working now the way i want. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

You could start by replacing all `NaN` values in the `datetime2` column with `datetime.now` value. Thus it would make it easier to compare `datetime1` to now if `datetime1` is `NaN`.

You can do it with :

```py
df["datetime2"] = df["datetime2"].fillna(value=pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize(),axis=1)
```

Then you hace only 2 conditions remaining :

- If `datetime1` column is empty, the result is `NaN`.
- Otherwise, the result is the difference between `datetime1` and `datetime2` column (as there is no `NaN` remaining in `datetime2` column).

You can perform this with :

```py
import numpy as np

df["Difference in H:m:s"] = np.where(
    df["datetime1"].isnull(),
    pd.NA,
    df["datetime2"] - df["datetime1"]
)
```

You can finally format your `Difference in H:m:s` in the required format with the function you provided :

```py
def strfdelta(tdelta, fmt):
    d = {"days": tdelta.days}
    d["hours"], rem = divmod(tdelta.seconds, 3600)
    d["minutes"], d["seconds"] = divmod(rem, 60)
    return fmt.format(**d)


df["Difference in H:m:s"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: strfdelta(
        x["Difference in H:m:s"],
        "{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}",
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

The complete code is :

```py
import numpy as np

# if datetime1/datetime2 aren't already datetime, apply `.to_datetime()`:
df["datetime1"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime1"])
df["datetime2"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime2"])

df["datetime2"] = df["datetime2"].fillna(value=pandas.to_datetime('today').normalize(),axis=1)

df["Difference in H:m:s"] = np.where(
    df["datetime1"].isnull(),
    pd.NA,
    df["datetime2"] - df["datetime1"]
)

def strfdelta(tdelta, fmt):
    d = {"days": tdelta.days}
    d["hours"], rem = divmod(tdelta.seconds, 3600)
    d["minutes"], d["seconds"] = divmod(rem, 60)
    return fmt.format(**d)


df["Difference in H:m:s"] = df.apply(
    lambda x: strfdelta(
        x["Difference in H:m:s"],
        "{hours:02d}:{minutes:02d}:{seconds:02d}",
    ),
    axis=1,
)
```

Comment: Thanks @AlexTorx